# How to get few column names among all columns in the one table with query in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='Submenu';
```

The above query gave all column names in `Submenu` table but I want only three column names of `Submenu` table.

Is there any way to get column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed this is SQL Server, so the below queries might not work on other RDBMS's).

If your question is how to find only the column names you need (presuming you know in advance which ones those are), you would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME='Submenu'
    AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3')
```

At this moment, you basically are requesting a list of any column within your table, without any restrictions whatsoever.

Alternatively, if you're looking only for the first three column names, this would work:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME='Submenu'
ORDER BY
    ORDERINAL_POSITION
```

In the latter case, you will have to determine how you want to sort the column names though (either by using something like `ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME`, in case you want them listed alphabetically, or `ORDER BY ORDERINAL_POSITION` in case you're trying to get them in the order they appear in the table).

If this is not what you meant, please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer
It works fine for me...
Thank you so much for perfect solution

Comment: @sagarpatil If this works for you, please mark it as an answer. That way future visitors to this question can see the solution that worked for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 3 COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Submenu';
```

As easy as that!

Comment: `LIMIT 3`? Question tagged with `SQL SERVER`.

Comment: Yes, you're right.
`SELECT TOP 3 COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Submenu';` in that case.